# Oracle SQL - update ids in oracle sql to be in sequential order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle SQL whose ids are in increasing, sequential order, but there are gaps in the ids due to editing, e.g. the ids are currently something like

- 22
- 23
- 24
- 32
- 33
- 44
- ...etc

I'd like to fix these gaps by just going through each row in the table and update them so there are no gaps. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If the ID is a primary key should not care about the gaps. The ID values are meaningless. So the answer to your question: "*The best way to do it is - to **not** do it*"

Comment: I'll echo @a_horse_with_no_name and add that if you are assigning meaning to an ID in any way where gaps are a problem, there is a fundamental problem with your schema.  You are probably better off adding an additional column for your numbering and leaving the IDs alone.

Comment: Additionally: what do you do with any row *referencing*  those IDs? You will need to "renumber" them as well.

Comment: If your ID numbers are generated by a sequence you will always have gaps appearing. e.g. sequence cached values may be aged out of the shared pool, transactions may not commit having used a sequence nextval etc etc. It is really OK to have gaps! If you want gap-free numbers in reports etc then just renumber them at report time using rownum or row_number().

Comment: No, you guys are right - Right now the ids are meaningless, I just wanted to order them as sort of an OCD thing, and keep things clean just incase they did matter in the future.

Comment: You accepted an answer which is not even working and didnot had a look at the answer which is  working fine. Is there any specific reason for this. Or is it like the answer which is not working for anyone is magically working for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following will work in Oracle:

```
update (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as newid) toupdate
    set id = newid
```

The above answer was accepted a long time ago.  It doesn't work.  I think the answer should have code that does work, so:

```
merge into t dest using
       (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as newid from t) src
       on (dest.rowid = src.rowid)
   when matched then update set id = newid;
```

Comment: @Gordon..Can you please post the full update statement. I just wanted to check once coz I feel "from clause" is missing here. And when i used it , I am getting error "data Manipulation operation not legal on this view"..My query goes like this  
update (select t.*, row_number() over (order by emp_id) as newid from employee t ) toupdate
    set emp_id = newid

Comment: @Raj_Te . . . If you have a question, then ask it as a question and not in a comment.

Comment: Done.. please reply at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789481/oracle-update-query-to-update-records-in-sequential-order

Comment: Surely a comment is more appropriate here as it's pointing out this answer doesn't actually work in Oracle? Curious that it was accepted.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . I added the correct answer using `merge`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It needs more work: you have typed `merge` not `merge into` and your `select` still has no `from` clause :-)

Comment: I have now fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single SQL statement as follows:

```
create table t as
  select rownum * 2 id
  from   dual 
  connect by level <= 10;

update t set id = (
  with tab as (
    select id, rownum r 
    from   (select id from t order by id)
  ) 
  select r from tab where t.id = tab.id
);

select * from t;

        ID
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 
         4 
         5 
         6 
         7 
         8 
         9 
        10
```

This will result in a full scan of `t` for every row in it, so will be very slow if `t` is "large". As the commenters have said, think very carefully before doing this; there are better ways to solve this "problem".

Answer (score 2):

use this one:

```
update mytable set id = ROWNUM;
```

Comment: Changing the primary key of a record may take you in devil's kitchen, and will mostly even not be possible (when used as a foreign key etc.).

Comment: @Uwe this is exactly what the OP wants to do though, so can't criticise the answer!  And this is by far the simplest solution, as long as there is no requirement to preserve the ordering of the ids (and why should there be?)

Answer (score 0):

I think U Should Execute this code

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR A
   IS
      SELECT ROWID DD
        FROM YOUR_TABLE;
   B   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   B := 1;
   FOR I IN A
   LOOP
      UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
         SET COLUMN_NAME = B
       WHERE ROWID = I.DD;
      B := B + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Just Replace `COLUMN_NAME` with your actual column name having wrong ids and then execute this and see the column values which are sorted accuratley.Thanks