# Oracle update query to update records in sequential order

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in Oracle SQL whose ids are in increasing, sequential order, but there are gaps in the ids due to editing, e.g. the ids are currently something like

```
22 
23 
24 
32 
33 
44 
...etc
```

I check one post and the solution provided was as below:

```
update (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as newid) toupdate
    set id = newid
```

[Solution Provided earlier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441897/oracle-sql-update-ids-in-oracle-sql-to-be-in-sequential-order/14441980?noredirect=1#comment64948060_14441980)

Now my query:
1) I guess the "From clause" is missing in the above query.

Updated query:

```
update (select t.*, 
              row_number() over (order by emp_id) as newid 
       from employee t ) toupdate 
set emp_id = newid;
```

2) When i run the above query, it gives me error "data Manipulation operation not legal on this view".

Can anyone explain how the mentioned solutions worked here. can anyone post the full update query. Thanks.

Comment: Googling that error it says you are updating a view, so is your "table" a Table or a View?  Also, why design something that places so much importance on a Number?  Does it really matter that it is sequential? https://community.oracle.com/thread/2485143?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @RegencySoftware he is updating a virtual view i.e. `update (select ...)`.  Some virtual views can be updated, but not all.  I agree with you that gaps in emp_id numbers should not be considered important.

Comment: My question is raised from a solution provided earlier. When i asked for clarification, I was asked to put my doubts as a question. Hence i did it.  Now looking for the solution. It would be great learning for me to know about this kind of update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457909/18747) to the same question you referenced shows how to do it:

```
update employee set emp_id = (
  with tab as (
    select emp_id, rownum r
    from   (select emp_id from employee order by emp_id)
  )
  select r from tab where employee.emp_id = tab.emp_id
);
```

That works.  You cannot update a view that contains an analytic function like row_number - see [Oracle 12C docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504), look for "Notes on Updatable Views".

Comment: Thanks for this but i was looking at the answer which got most votes. I wanted to understand what Gordon tried to do which i want to learn in future.

Comment: Oh I see.  I don't believe Gordon's solution can work because [as documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) "The view must not contain...An aggregate or analytic function" which `row_number` is.

Comment: That's what i questioned their if you observe in the link and the reply from there was that I should ask it as a question so i did..To my surprise it got 2 upvotes as well,,,:-))).

Comment: Thanks tony for your efforts but as mentioned earlier, this is not my question. I had a question out of the solution provided and when asked the expert asked me to post my query as a question. So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `merge`, but you'd need to join on something other than `emp_id` as you want to update that column. If there are no other unique columns you can use the `rowid`:

```
merge into employee target
using (select rowid, row_number() over (order by emp_id) as emp_id from employee) source
on (source.rowid = target.rowid)
when matched then update set target.emp_id = source.emp_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i was looking at the answer which got most votes. I wanted to understand what Gordon tried to do which i want to learn in future.

Comment: I think (unusually) Gordon's answer is wrong; not sure why it's accepted as it doesn't work in Oracle... A comment was probably more appropriate in this case, though maybe your initial one didn't male it entirely clear that it just doesn't work as written.

Comment: Well I raised a concern over there. Am sure either he is wrong or i/we are getting him wrong. He must explain here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easiest approach :

> update mytable set id = ROWNUM;

[Oracle SQL - update ids in oracle sql to be in sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441897/oracle-sql-update-ids-in-oracle-sql-to-be-in-sequential-order/38785315#38785315)