# Solving a complex sql subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query and i know exactly what the problem is. It returns more than one column from it's inside select statement while it is going to update only one column. The point is the second column is used for the condition. 
How can i reach my goal ? Is there any specific sql syntax.

```
update xaddress B set (B.xrank)=
(select a.x1001olcsrl,row_number() over(partition by a.x1001olcsrl order by a.x1001olcsrl) as rnk
from xaddress a) 
where x1001olcsrl=B.x1001olcsrl
```

Comment: This would be easier [using a `merge`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38790076/266304). Are you sure you want to store/maintain that rank - why not have a wrapper view that generates it on the fly?

Comment: It would be simpler if you would explain what you are tying to do. The inner query makes no sense: select a column, and a row number where you partition and order by the same column? what's that supposed to do? What it does do is, if there are no duplicates, it will always return 1; and if there are, it will return more than one row for each duplicated x1001olcsrl value, and the error (even if you use MERGE, the correct solution) will be that there are too many ROWS in the subquery, not just too many columns.

Comment: @alex I agree with you, but this could be executed every update, perhaps by trigger, if rank performance is crucial

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more sub query to select only one column. Replace 'Value' with your original value.

for single row update.

```
update xaddress 
set xrank = (Select rnk from (select a.x1001olcsrl,row_number() over(partition by a.x1001olcsrl order by a.x1001olcsrl) as rnk 
            from xaddress) where x1001olcsrl= 'Value')
where x1001olcsrl= 'Value'
```

for whole table update.

```
With CTE  As
(
 select x1001olcsrl,row_number() over(partition by x1001olcsrl order by x1001olcsrl as rnk 
 from xaddress
)
update xaddress
SET xrank = rnk
FROM xaddress a
INNER JOIN CTE b ON a.x1001olcsrl = b.x1001olcsrl
```

Comment: The point seems to be to update all rows inn the table, not for a single value; but as the value is duplicated the subquery will still return multiple rows. You would need to correlate on a unique columns (or rowid).

Comment: Okay, so here we apply With CTE

Answer (score 0):

Use `MERGE`, which is oracle's version of update-with-join:

```
MERGE INTO xaddress a
USING (select
         x1001olcsrl,
         row_number() over(partition by x1001olcsrl order by x1001olcsrl) rnk
       from xaddress) x
ON x.x1001olcsrl = a.x1001olcsrl
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET xrank = rnk
```

Comment: Does this make sense to you? Select x100.... and row_number partitioned and ordered by the same x100... .?  What will that return? I pointed that out in a Comment nine hours ago.